# [Error]HTML5, Jquery - LightBox only shows latest information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

```
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Quick Simple Light Box</title>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <style type="text/css">

                    body
                    {
                        font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
                    }

                    .backdrop
                    {
                        position:absolute;
                        top:0px;
                        left:0px;
                        width:100%;
                        height:100%;
                        background:#000;
                        opacity: .0;
                        filter:alpha(opacity=0);
                        z-index:50;
                        display:none;
                    }


                    .box
                    {
                        position:absolute;
                        top:20%;
                        left:30%;
                        width:500px;
                        height:300px;
                        background:#ffffff;
                        z-index:51;
                        padding:10px;
                        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                        border-radius: 5px;
                        -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
                        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
                        box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #444444;
                        display:none;
                    }

                    .close
                    {
                        float:right;
                        margin-right:6px;
                        cursor:pointer;
                    }

                    </style>

                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        $(document).ready(function(){

                            $('.lightbox').click(function(){
                                $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'.50'}, 300, 'linear');
                                $('.box').animate({'opacity':'1.00'}, 300, 'linear');
                                $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
                            });

                            $('.close').click(function(){
                                close_box();
                            });

                            $('.backdrop').click(function(){
                                close_box();
                            });

                        });

                        function close_box()
                        {
                            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 300, 'linear', function(){
                                $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
                            });
                        }

                    </script>

                </head>
                <body>

                <h1>This is my webpage...</h1>
                <a href="#" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>

                <div class="backdrop"></div>
                <div class="box"><div class="close">x</div>This is the lightbox!!!</div>

                </body>
            </html>
```

---

Hello, I've an issue with the above lightbox code.

It apparently only shows the latest information, for example.

```
                <a href="#" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>

                <div class="backdrop"></div>
                <div class="box"><div class="close">x</div>This is the lightbox!!!</div>




                <a href="#" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>

                <div class="backdrop"></div>
                <div class="box"><div class="close">x</div>This is the lightbox123456!!!</div>
```

It will shows This is the lightbox123456!!! regardless of what you click.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It in fact shows both, if you change `.box`'s position to `relative`, you can see both box appear. I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c8t2ezb5/) to show the effect.

As you only want it to show the box after the anchor, you can do:

1. Move the `.backdrop` to the last of the body, and only keep one, as it won't with the anchor you click.
2. Use the `.next()` to select the `.box` directly after the anchor, then use `.add` to add the `.backdrop` to group.
3. Animate on them.

If the `.backdrop` varies by the anchor you clicked, I'd suggest wrap both `.box` and `.backdrop` to a container, then use `$(this).next('.container').find('.box, .backdrop')` to get the targets. Or wrap the anchor in the container too, then use `$(this).siblings('.box, .backdrop')` to select.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.lightbox').click(function() {
    // Get the target box, and the only backdrop
    
    // Because they will apply different opacity, we have to get them separately first.
    var $box = $(this).next('.box');
    var $backdrop = $('.backdrop');
    
    // Group them.
    var $targets = $box.add($backdrop);
    
    // Ensure the targets's display.
    $targets.css('display', 'block');
    
    // Separate the animation of each element if you want different parameters. or chain them.
    $backdrop.animate({
      'opacity': '.50'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $box.animate({
      'opacity': '1.00'
    }, 300, 'linear');
    $targets.css('display', 'block');
  });

  $('.close').click(function() {
    close_box();
  });

  $('.backdrop').click(function() {
    close_box();
  });

});

function close_box() {
  $('.backdrop, .box').animate({
    'opacity': '0'
  }, 300, 'linear', function() {
    $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'none');
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}
.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  opacity: .0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  z-index: 50;
  display: none;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 51;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #444444;
  display: none;
}
.close {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>


<div class="box">
  <div class="close">x</div>This is the lightbox!!!
</div>
 
<a href="#" class="lightbox">Open Lightbox</a>
<div class="box">
  <div class="close">x</div>This is the lightbox123456!!!</div>

<div class="backdrop"></div>
```